# Mongoose Compound Index Unique + Sparse

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to create an index which ensures, that I don't have a duplicate `serialNr` within the combination of a `manufacturer` + `art`. But some items don't have a `serialNr`. These I don't want to check/index.

### Code

`mySchema.index({ serialNr: 1, art: 1 , manufacturer: 1, deleted: 1}, { unique: true, sparse: true)`

I tried it also with adding a partial Filter:
`partialFilterExpression: { serialNr: {$ne:null} }` to the index options.

### Question

How can I index it that inserting:
`[{art: 'a', manufacturer:'a', deleted:null}, {art: 'a', manufacturer:'a', deleted:null}]` passes

and

`[{serialNr: '123', art: 'a', manufacturer:'a', deleted:null}, {serialNr: '123', art: 'a', manufacturer:'a', deleted:null}]`fails

I'm not trying to save:
`[{serialNr: null, art: 'a', manufacturer:'a', deleted:null}, {serialNr: null, art: 'a', manufacturer:'a', deleted:null}]`

---

The mongo docs state, that it should not be indexed if a field is missing in a compound index:

> Sparse indexes selects documents to index solely based on the
> existence of the indexed field, or for compound indexes, the existence
> of the indexed fields.
> https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-partial/

### EDIT:

#### New Index

`implantSchema.index({ serialNr: 1, art: 1 , manufacturer: 1, deleted: 1}, { unique: true, partialFilterExpression: { serialNr: {$exists:true} }})`

Before I make changes on the index I drop my `collection` in my dev-database, to ensure that there is no old index existing. This is the new index which is returned on `db.items.getIndexes()`

```json
/* 0 */
{
    "0": {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "LOC_db.items"
    },
    "1": {
        "v" : 1,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "serialNr" : 1,
            "art" : 1,
            "manufacturer" : 1,
            "deleted" : 1
        },
        "name" : "serialNr_1_art_1_manufacturer_1_deleted_1",
        "ns" : "LOC_db.items",
        "partialFilterExpression" : {
            "serialNr" : {
                "$exists" : true
            }
        },
        "background" : true
    }
}
```

#### Data

- I have a pre save hook where I check the value of `serialNr`, which does not exist before, the `dup error` is returned.
- When querying the database there is no `doc` existing which has `null`, `""` as value for the `serialNr`.
- The query `db.items.find({ serialNr: {$exists:true} })` does not match any items.

#### Error

```
insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: LOC_db.items.$serialNr_1_art_1_manufacturer_1_deleted_1 dup key: { : null, : "Robo", : "Olymp", : null }
```

### Additional Information

Maybe the error is related to:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2457

Comment: What is the question? You already answered yourself, use unique index with sparse... Also why do you index deleted?

Comment: That does not work, thats why the question is there. I index deleted, because it is data which needs to be kept even if the user deletes it. So deleted is either null or the date when the user deleted the data.

Comment: Actually I don't save ´null´ on deleted just a date if it was deleted, that was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were actually quite close to the solution, all you need to use this when creating index :

```
partialFilterExpression: { serialNr: {$exists:true} }
```

---

Be sure to have at least 3.2 version of mongo

---

Example :

```
db.col.createIndex({a:1, b:1},{unique:true, partialFilterExpression: { a: {$exists:true} })
db.col.save({a:50, b:27}) //pass
db.col.save({a:50, b:27}) //fails
db.col.save({b:27}) //pass
db.col.save({b:27}) //pass
db.col.save({b:27}) //pass
db.col.save({a:50, b:27}) //fails
db.col.save({a:50}) //pass
db.col.save({a:50}) //fails
```

---

PS : Maybe you can do little "hack" and use this : `partialFilterExpression: { serialNr: {$exists:true}, serialNr: {$gte:0} }`

I tried using $ne, but it was throwing me an error.

Comment: I can't get it working. I added an edit above with the current situation.

Comment: @AndiGiga - you are obviously trying to add document, where serialNr exists and has value null... and you are saying you are not doing it.

Comment: I see the `null`in the error msg as well, but I don't pass a `null` value. As described in the edit above: the previous saved entries don't contain any value for serialNr and the current saved `doc`does not contain any value for the `serialNr` in the pre save hook.

Comment: My versions are: `"mongoose": "^4.0.2",` and MongoDB shell version: is `2.6.6` I update them now and check if the error persists.

Comment: @AndiGiga - What about your mongoose model? If you set default to null for serialNr, it will pass the null. So take out the "default:null" for it and you should be fine.

Comment: Also no default: `null`. With version `v3.2.4` it seems to work. The important part is: `Be sure to have at least 3.2 version of mongo`