# Mongoose unique compound index if other field is false or doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have item names that need to be unique for each country if they are not flagged as inactive, so I would like to set some kind of compound index to enforce this if the inactive flag is not set at all or if the inactive flag is set to false. Can this be accomplished with an index or would I have to write a pre save hook?

```
let itemSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    country: String,
    inactive: Boolean
})

itemSchema.index(
    {
        name: 1,
        country: 1
    },
    {
        // How do I set it to unique if inactive is false or does not exist?
        unique: true
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and solved it with the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922127/9111494).

```
itemSchema.index(
    {
        name: 1,
        country: 1
    },
    {
        unique: true,
        partialFilterExpression: { inactive: { $eq: false } }
    }
)
```

I haven't tried it with `$exists`, but presumably you can modify the `partialFilterExpression` to include it as follows:

```
partialFilterExpression: { inactive: { $eq: false, $exists: false } }
```